# Moving from ubuntu 10.10 to 11.10 dependecy eigen not found

Tags: rosdep, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have upgraded my system from Ubuntu 10.10 too 11.10 and changed ros from diamondback to fuerte , .. I found that dependency eigen no longer exists? .. I need to copy old packages i made to new version, and i get this error for eigen .. 'package_name' depends on non existent package eigen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33336/moving-from-ubuntu-10.10-to-11.10-dependecy-eigen-not-found/) by [anonymous2029](https://answers.ros.org/users/2029/anonymous2029/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-05**:
type "rosdep resolve eigen" what comes out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Eigen changed](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eigen) from a ROS depend to a rosdep system dependency between Diamondback and Fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1